# How to view the content of a gzipped file “abc.gz” without actually extracting it?

Tags: shell, unix, gzip

How to view the content of a gzipped file `abc.gz` without extracting it ?
I tried to find a way to see content without unzip but i did not find way.

Comment: You mean without gunzip? unzip doesn't decompress .gz files.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the command below to see the file without replacing it with the decompressed content:

```
gunzip -c filename.gz
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `zcat` to see content without extraction.

```
zcat abc.gz
```

From the manual:

> `zcat` is identical to `gunzip -c`.  (On some systems, `zcat` may be
>   installed as `gzcat` to preserve the original link to `compress`.)
>   `zcat` uncompresses either a list of files on the command line or its
>   standard input and writes the uncompressed data on standard output. 
>   `zcat` will uncompress files that have the correct magic number whether
>   they have a `.gz` suffix or not.

Answer (score 1):

Plain text:

```
cat abc
```

Gzipped text:

```
zcat abc.gz
```